# Get the PID using :via with :gproc

Tags: elixir

I'm using `:gproc` to name some dynamically started GenServers but I want to send messages to those process and I need the PID and I'm unsure of how to get them with `gproc` if I'm not using `:gproc.reg/1`.

Basically this is the part of the GenServer

```
  def start_link(name) do
    IO.inspect(via_tuple(name), label: "NAME")
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{name: name, songs: []},
                        name: via_tuple(name))
  end

  def queue(name, songs) do
    GenServer.cast(via_tuple(name), {:queue, songs})
  end

  def dispatch(name) do
    GenServer.cast(via_tuple(name), :dispatch)
  end

  def via_tuple(name) do
    {:via, :gproc, {:n, :l, {:name, name}}}
  end
```

and in the `init` function I'm just scheduling a task to send some messages but I need the PID. I thought about some ways of doing this but they're hacks which don't look good. Which can be the correct way of retrieving PIDs here?

I'm not sure about this part but, I'm just registering names here and not actual processes to be retrieved, right? If that's the case how can I solve that problem too?

Comment: `:gproc.where(name)`?

Comment: I ended using the Registry module @Dogbert

Answer (score 1):

Given your example code above it would be...

```
:gproc.where({:n, :l, {:name, name}})
```

I had the same issue. Finally found it explained with an [example here](http://blog.rusty.io/2009/09/16/g-proc-erlang-global-process-registry/).